# Sort one column only, keeping remaining columns untouched

Tags: text-processing, sort, columns

How to (numerically) sort a specific column in a text file, without affecting other columns (irrespective of whether they are sorted or unsorted)? On other threads I found `-s` argument, but it does sort other columns.

Observation

```
$ cat tmp.txt
1 1
2 3
5 4
1 3

$ sort -s -n -k1,1 tmp.txt
1 1
1 3
2 3
5 4
```

Comment: No, `-s` implies stable sort.  You need to show your observation.

Comment: What's wrong with the output?  What did you expect?

Comment: @devnull second column should remain as it is.

Comment: Interchange the first and last lines of your sample file and run the same command.  You'll figure.

Comment: Why will the second column remain as is?  `sort` sorts __lines of input__ based on the criteria that you provide.

Comment: because I want it to remain as it is, i m asking how that can be achieved since it's not achieved with `-s` flag.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken there isn't a command that you could use _out-of-the-box_ to do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't achieve what you want using `sort` alone.

You could `cut` the input file, feed relevant part to `sort`, and `paste` those.

```
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 input | sort -n) <(cut -d' ' -f2- input)
1 1
1 3
2 4
5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in `perl`:

```
perl -lane '
 push @first , $F[0];
 push @second, $F[1];
 END{
    @first = sort { $a <=> $b } @first;
    print "$fist[$_] $second[$_]" for (0..$#first)
 }' your_file
```

It assumes the first column (the one to be sorted) consists only of numerical data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on solaris and needed an answer without sort -s and the accepted answer wasn't working for me.
Joeyg on unix.com had the answer:
[sort-one-column-only](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/165248-sort-one-column-only.html)

```
cat tmp.txt
1 5
2 3
5 4
1 3

#Sort by 1st column leaving second stable sorted by the 1st.
cat -n tmp.txt | sort -k 2,2 | awk '{print $2,$3}'
1 5
1 3
2 3
5 4

#Sort by 2nd column leaving first stable sorted by the 2nd.
cat -n tmp.txt | sort -k 3,3 | awk '{print $2,$3}'
2 3
1 3
5 4
1 5
```

Different interpretation via comment is to sort a single column without affecting the rest:

```
#Sort by 1st column leaving other columns untouched:
cat -n tmp.txt | sort -k 2,2 | awk '{a[NR]=$2;b[$1]=$3} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]" "b[i]}'
1 5
1 3
2 4
5 3

Explanation:
cat -n adds rownums to force sort to do "sort -s" without GNU sort.
sort -k 2,2 sorts by the 1st column

NR is a built-in variable that holds the row num.
a[NR]=$2; puts the sorted column in a[1..4]
b[$1]=$3; puts the "unsorted" 2nd column in b[rownum from cat]
Then the for loop just outputs the two arrays.
```

What I needed which was the newest *unique* column 3 entries in the file.  e.g.

```
cat tmp2.txt
5|1|3
4|2|1
1|3|2
3|4|1
2|5|2

cat -n tmp2.txt | sort -k 3 -rut '|' | awk '{print $2}'
5|1|3
2|5|2
3|4|1
```

Comment: did not work. It gave me output 
`first column - 1 
2 
5 
1 
` second column `1 3 4 3`

Comment: @user13107 did you try running the first block cat -n tmp | sort -k 2,2 | awk '{print $2,$3}' ? The trick is in cat -n.  Which outputs line numbers before the sort.  Will retest tomorrow.

Comment: @user13107 retested and expanded the answer.

Comment: your first column is not unchanged in first example. it's 2 1 5 1 in the end and it was 1 2 5 1 initially.

Comment: @user13107 I think I understand the question now. You may wish to edit your original question to give an example of what you wanted. I had assumed you wanted a stable sort that left other columns in their original order relative to the new sort.

Comment: i thought it was clear from the question and comments on it. anyway thanks for your help. you can edit the answer if you find another new way of doing it!